# kickout process to publish tables in SAS DIS

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I have a job which does some matching but may produce duplicates. When this happens, I want the job to create a table containing these duplicates and send an email with the data.

Putting aside the conditionality for the moment (on whether duplicates were actually produced), I can't even seem to get the email to send.

I have tried selecting a `Publish to Email` transformation and follow [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/65016/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1cgt4w29fjjs3n1p487ilkipgop.htm) link as best as I could, but I get the errors

> ERROR: Email host ****** not found
>   ERROR: Unable to publish package to email address ******
>   ERROR: EMAIL transport engine encountered errors while publishing the package.
>   ERROR: Email host ****** not found. Package end successful

where ****** are strings that I am obscuring. One issue is that the mentioned link asks me to show the output tab, but checking the indicated box has no effect and the output tab still cannot be seen. I do not know if this is what is causing my error.

Much Gratitude for any help with this.

**UPDATE:**

I can now get the output tab to display. Toggling the option only takes effect after closing and reopening the job. The other (main) issue remains.

Comment: Are you able to send automated emails via the host in question using any other application?

Comment: Not that I know of. I asked a colleague if he can do it in SAS EG and he said he can't and that he gets the same error. Another colleague believes that it's a permissions thing and that the feature probably isn't part of our license. Any idea if that hypothesis might be correct? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to send emails using base sas code? i.e. via `filename email`?

Comment: please reach out to your SAS administrator for this. Either email options have not been setup correctly in SAS or maybe your SAS admin does not want any emailing to be done from your SAS server.

Comment: Thanks sushil. That turned out to be what was needed. You can post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reach out to your SAS administrator for this. Either email options have not been setup correctly in SAS or maybe your SAS admin does not want any emailing to be done from your SAS server.